# SSH-agent not loading when remotely accessing the machine

Tags: linux, ssh, xorg, openssh, gnome-keyring

I have this user account that I have correctly configured to manage my keys to ssh to other instances.

When I sit in front of the machine my configuration works as described in my ~/.ssh/config file:

Part of it:

```
Host vm0-test
   User test
   HostName vm0.test.lab
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/vm

Host vm1-test
   User test
   HostName vm1.test.lab
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/vm

Host vm2-test
   User test
   HostName vm2.test.lab
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/vm
```

But every time I ssh remotely to this machine I need to perform manually this steps:

```
remote $ eval `ssh-agent`
remote $ ssh-add ~/.ssh/vm
```

How can I force it load my local configuration every time I ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `config` file is not starting an agent. It is just providing three aliases with assigned key files to be used. If this key file (`~/.ssh/vm`) is protected by a passphrase (as it should be) and no agent is running you have to type this phrase each time you use the key. That is why we use agents.

Your agent must be started somewhere else. And if it is not started on remote login, it may be started within the startup of your graphics session (some key service). That's why you must start it manually for remote ssh.

So what can you do?

1. Find the place your ssh-agent is started to know why it is not done for remote sessions.
2. Do start ssh-agent from within `.profile`, e.g. have a look at [that](http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh) .

If your `.profile` is checking for an already running agent, it will not disturb the agent of a graphical session. This will work for both, local graphical and remote text sessions.